# What's the most elegant way to find word pairs in a text with Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Given a list of word pairs

```
val terms = ("word1a", "word1b") :: ("word2a", "word2b") :: ... :: Nil
```

What's the most elegant way in Scala to test if **at least one** of the pairs occur in a text? The test should terminate as quick as possible when it hits the first match. How would you solve that?

EDIT: To be more precise I want to know if **both words of a pair** appear somewhere (not necessarily in order) in the text. If that's the case for one of the pairs in the list the method should return `true`. It's not necessary that the matched pair is returned, neither it's important if more than one pair matches.

Comment: One thing that is ambiguous about your question : are you asking for a result which is a `List[Boolean]` (that is, a boolean for each pair), or a single `Boolean`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> val text = Set("blah1", "word2b", "blah2", "word2a")
text: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(blah1, word2b, blah2)

scala> terms.exists{case (a,b) => text(a) && text(b)}
res12: Boolean = true
```

EDIT: Note that using a set to represent the tokens in the text makes the lookup from the `contains` much more efficient.  You wouldn't want to use something sequential like a List for that.

EDIT 2: Updated for clarification in requirement!

EDIT 3: changed `contains` to `apply` per the suggestion in the comment

Comment: This solution works and seems pretty short. To get the text as set of tokens is a good idea.

Comment: As `Set`s themselves are functions, you can condense the code further to `text(a) && text(b)`.

Comment: This fails the "terminate as quick as possible" criterion--you need to read your entire text as a set, which means you are guaranteed to read it all once.  It meets the elegance criterion, however.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: It depends on how you define "terminate as quick as possible": it may move through the whole text but only looks at as many pairs as it has to.  Depending on what your data looks like (text length, number of repeated words, number of pairs, etc) it's hard to say which would be preferred as the fail-fast condition.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Good call.  Thanks.

Comment: @dhg - If the set of search terms is long compared to the text, then I agree; you want to fail fast on the search terms.  I don't think this is the typical case, but it can happen.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - seems like the ambiguous wording of your question means I answered a different question**:

Because you are essentially asking for either of the pair; you might as well flatten all these into one big set.

```
val words = (Set.empty[String] /: terms) { case (s, (w1, w2)) => s + w1 + w2 }
```

Then you are just asking whether any of these exist in the text:

```
text.split("\\s") exists words
```

This is fast because we can use the structure of a `Set` to lookup quickly whether the word is contained in the text; it terminates early due to the "exists":

```
scala> val text = "blah1  blah2 word2b"
text: java.lang.String = blah1  blah2 word2b
```

**In the case that your text is very long**, you may wish to `Stream` it, so that the next word to test is lazily computed, rather than split the String into substrings up-front:

```
scala> val Word = """\s*(.*)""".r
Word: scala.util.matching.Regex = \s*(.*)

scala> def strmWds(text : String) : Stream[String] = text match {
     | case Word(nxt) => val (word, rest) = nxt span (_ != ' '); word #:: strmWds(rest)
     | case _         => Stream.empty
     | }
strmWds: (text: String)Stream[String]
```

Now you can:

```
scala> strmWds(text) exists words
res4: Boolean = true

scala> text.split("\\s") exists words
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Sorry, if the question was misleading in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that *both* elements of the pair have to appear in the text, but it doesn't matter where, and it doesn't matter *which* pair appears.

I'm not sure this is the most elegant, but it's not bad, and it's fairly fast if you expect that the text probably has the words (and thus you don't need to read all of it), and if you can generate an iterator that will give you the words one at a time:

```
case class WordPair(one: String, two: String) {
  private[this] var found_one, found_two = false
  def check(s: String): Boolean = {
    if (s==one) found_one = true
    if (s==two) found_two == true
    found_one && found_two
  }
  def reset {
    found_one = false
    found_two = false
  }
}

val wordpairlist = terms.map { case (w1,w2) => WordPair(w1,w2) }

// May need to wordpairlist.foreach(_.reset) first, if you do this on multiple texts
text.iterator.exists(w => wordpairlist.exists(_.check(w)))
```

You could further improve things by putting all the terms in a set, and not even bothering to check the wordpairlist unless the word from the text was in that set.

If you mean that the words have to occur next to each other in order, you then should change `check` to

```
def check(s: String) = {
  if (found_one && s==two) found_two = true
  else if (s==one) { found_one = true; found_two = false }
  else found_two = false
  found_one && found_two
}
```

Comment: You are right, both words should appear somewhere in the text but not necessarily in order. I updated the question to be more precise on this point.